# Django returning form error but the input seems to be valid

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

One of my models is a Product model which has 3 different price fields, so that one of its prices can be chosen when creating an order. I created a select input in one of my forms to allow the user to choose one of the prices, but when the form is submitted, Django returns an error telling me to introduce a valid number, even though I checked the request.POST and the value it's sending is a valid number.

**models.py:**

```
class Product(models.Model):
    ...
    price_1 = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True, default=0) # Separador de miles
    price_2 = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True, default=0) # Separador de miles
    price_3 = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True, default=0) # Separador de miles
```

**forms.py:**

```
class CartAddProductForm(forms.Form):
    price = forms.DecimalField()
    quantity = forms.IntegerField(
        label ='Amount'
    )
    override = forms.BooleanField(required=False, initial=False, widget=forms.HiddenInput)
```

**views.py**:

```
@require_POST
def cart_add(request, product_id):
    cart = Cart(request)
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=product_id)
    form = CartAddProductForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        cd = form.cleaned_data
        cart.add(product=product, quantity=cd['quantity'], price=cd['price'], override_quantity=cd['override'])
    return redirect('cart:cart_detail')
```

**Template:**

```
<form action="{% url 'cart:cart_add' product.id %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="id_price">Precio</label>
        <select name="price" id="id_price" class="select2 form-control" data-toggle="select2" required>
            <option value="{{ product.price_1 }}" selected>Precio retail: ${{ product.price_1|intcomma }}</option>
            {% if product.price_2 %}
            <option value="{{ product.price_2 }}">Precio mayorista: ${{ product.price_2|intcomma }}</option>
            {% endif %}
            {% if product.price_3 %}
            <option value="{{ product.price_3 }}">Otro precio: ${{ product.price_3|intcomma }}</option>
            {% endif %}
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="id_quantity"></label>
        <input data-toggle="touchspin" type="number" value="1" data-bts-max="100000" required id="id_quantity" name="quantity" data-bts-button-down-class="btn btn-danger" data-bts-button-up-class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="hidden" name="override" value="False" id="id_override">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary">
        <i class="uil-plus-circle"></i>
        Agregar a la orden
    </button>
</form>
```

When debugging the view, `form.is_valid()` returns `False`. When checking `form.errors`, it effectively shows `{'price': ['Enter a valid number.']}`, but when checking `request.POST`, it shows `'price': ['40000,00'], 'quantity': ['1'], 'override': ['False']`, so the number is valid, but for some reason it is not passing to the `is_valid()` method as a valid number. Why would that be?

Answer (score 0):

Could this be a localization issue?

```
price = forms.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, localize=True)
```

The comma as decimal might be causing the form to fail.